# Laravel Routing - Best way to differentiate routes with same format

Tags: laravel, routes

Say I have a database of *items*, each belonging to a country, county and a city. I want to have routes to list all of the *items* within a singular country, county or a city. Each country/county/city has a slug, for example `france` for `France` that is to be used in URL.

I want all the routes to have the same format:
`/items-in-{slug}`, so for example `/items-in-france` or `/items-in-paris`.

However, the `slug` can be a slug of one of multiple Models. What is the best set up for this sort of situation? I can think of 3 main options:

1. A single route that will catch all matching URLs, which will run a specialised `RoutingController` or similar, which will then in turn check which Model slug represents and propogate to the correct controller method (for example, `viewInCountry($slug)` or `viewInCity($slug)`)
2. One route for each type of Model, and putting restrictions on each route that would only accept one of the existing slugs (i.e. fetch all of the slugs and generate a *regex* that will only accept one of the existing slugs)
3. Fetch all Models (countries/cities/counties) and generate a Route for each one

All options seem a little hacky and I am wondering if there is a more elegant solution to this.

Answer (score 2):

I would go for the second option, except don't use a regex to accept existing slugs. Instead you could write your own model route binding resolution logic as mentioned [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#explicit-binding) under 'Customizing The Resolution Logic'. Something like this could probably do the trick:

```
// Put this in your RouteServiceProvider.php
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    Route::bind('slug', function ($value) {
        $country = App\Country::where('slug', $value)->first();
        if ($country !== null) {
            return $country;
        }
        $city = App\City::where('slug', $value)->first();
        if ($city !== null) {
            return $city;
        }

        // Repeat for each model.

        // 404 in case no model has been matched.
        abort(404).
    });
}
```

Alternatively if you are willing to adjust the url a bit, then you could create a route and a controller per model. That would require you to have urls like `/items/france` or `items/paris` etc.

Comment: I get what you're saying. Isn't a regex better performance-wise though? With the route caching there would be no need to run SQL queries, where as this method will run 1-3 queries on every route just to get to the right place?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure route cache works if you create the slugs dynamically. If it does, then it the solution depends on how often the models change. If routes are cached it also means new, deleted or changed models won't work as expected.